# If and else Statements in While loop" for C++

Tags: c++, if-statement, while-loop

I have a question regarding if & else statements in a while loop.

I wanted to establish a few things in my program:

- wanted user to only input 4 letter characters without the use of numbers and symbols.
- converting each those letters into ints(Ascii val.)

To make it easier to understand if confused,

Program 1st asks for 4 letter word.
User places input. If input contains at least:

- a non-letter character, then Program asks User for new Input.

If input only contain letters Program checks input for # of letters.

If input doesn't have ___ :

- 4 letters, Program asks User for new Input.

Otherwise Program proceeds with determining Int value of each letter

---

Okay so heres my Program so far: ** not sure if this correct for

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string input;
    int input0 = input[0];  
    int input1 = input[1];  
    int input2 = input[2];
    int input3 = input[3];
    cout << "\nEnter a 4-letter word (Keep it clean!).\n";
  while(cin>>input){
    cout << endl << input << " has " << input.length() << " letters." << endl; 
        if (int(input[0]) > 64 || int(input[0]) < 91 || int(input[0]) > 96 || int(input[0]) < 123 || 
            int(input[1]) > 64 || int(input[1]) < 91 || int(input[1]) > 96 || int(input[1]) < 123 ||
            int(input[2]) > 64 || int(input[2]) < 91 || int(input[2]) > 96 || int(input[2]) < 123 ||
            int(input[3]) > 64 || int(input[3]) < 91 || int(input[3]) > 96 || int(input[3]) < 123) {
                if (input.length()!=5 && input.length()>3)
                    cout << "\n the int value of the " << input[0] << " is " << int(input[0]) << endl;
                    cout << "\n the int value of the " << input[1] << " is " << int(input[1]) << endl;
                    cout << "\n the int value of the " << input[2] << " is " << int(input[2]) << endl;
                    cout << "\n the int value of the " << input[3] << " is " << int(input[3]) << endl;
                else cout << input << "is not a 4-letter word.\nPlease try again." << endl;
        }
        else cout << input << " contains number(s) and or symbol(s).\nPlease try again." << endl;
  }
}
```

I got 2 errors:

- > error: expected '}' before 'else'
- > error: 'else' without a previous 'if'

Comment: Thanks for the tip Nicky! that managed to run the program, but I got a weird result: i placed a number  among the 4 characters asked [5tar], it still gives  the int values including the numbers int value when its supposed to ask User to try again.

Comment: That's because your logic is mental, using entirely logical-OR in a way that will _always_ result in `true`.  See my answer for a nicer alternative using `isalpha`.  Consider this: _What number is greater than 64, or is less than 91?_  Of course, the answer is: _All numbers_.

Answer (score 1):

This fairly gnarly bunch of statements is to blame:

```
if (input.length()!=5 && input.length()>3)
    cout << "\n the int value of the " << input[0] << " is " << int(input[0]) << endl;
// Not part of if-statement:
    cout << "\n the int value of the " << input[1] << " is " << int(input[1]) << endl;
    cout << "\n the int value of the " << input[2] << " is " << int(input[2]) << endl;
    cout << "\n the int value of the " << input[3] << " is " << int(input[3]) << endl;
else cout << input << "is not a 4-letter word.\nPlease try again." << endl;
```

You need to enclose all those `cout` statements (up until the `else`) in braces `{`, `}`.

I'd just like to make a point about the character tests you're doing.  It looks like you're checking whether the characters are letters, but are using the least-readable, least-portable approach.  Use `std::isalpha` instead.  In fact, you can accomplish the whole thing with this:

```
if( std::all_of( input.begin(), input.begin() + 4, [](char c){ return (bool)isalpha(c); } ) )
{
    //...
}
```

You should do the tests *after* ensuring the input is the correct length, or you will have undefined behaviour.  So let's do that:

```
while( cin>>input )
{
    cout << endl << input << " has " << input.length() << " letters." << endl; 
    if( input.length() != 4 )
    {
        cout << input << "is not a 4-letter word.\nPlease try again." << endl;
    }
    else if( any_of( input.begin(), input.end(), [](char c){ return !isalpha(c); } ) )
    {
        cout << input << " contains number(s) and or symbol(s).\nPlease try again." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        // I assume you want to exit the loop here.
        break;
    }
}
```

Notice I flipped the `all_of` statement around to the inverse ("any character is not a letter"), for better readability because the lambda no longer needs a cast for automatic type-deduction:

```
if( any_of( input.begin(), input.end(), [](char c){ return !isalpha(c); } ) ) ...
```